# Dynamically added event handler?

Tags: c#, forms

Ok, It was not clearly explained, how can I search for control name on all forms?

```
  ` void No1(Form a, int x, int y)
    {
        No2(a, x, y);
    }
    void No2(Form a, int x, int y)
    {
        Button b1 = new Button();
        b1.Location = new Point(x, y);
        b1.Click += new EventHandler(b1_click);
        b1.Name = "OgO4sEVm6asqnw";
        a.Controls.Add(b1);
    }
    void b1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a.Controls.RemoveByKey("OgO4sEVm6asqnw");
        No1(a, x, y);   //I have no way to get a, x and y, 
                        //since I don't know on witch form b1 is
    }`
```

Hope this explains it better..

Comment: Its hard to parse out what you are trying to do from the giant block of text. Can you re-format, provide an example, maybe some sample code  or pseudocode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **DO** know on which form `b1` is by casting the `sender`...

```
void b1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Button)
    {
        var b1 = (Button) sender;
        b1.Parent.Controls.RemoveByKey(b1.Name);
        No1(b1.TopLevelControl, b1.Location.X, b1.Location.Y);
    }                   
}
```

The property [TopLevelControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.toplevelcontrol%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) gives you the Form and `Parent` gives you the ControlContainer (can be the Form but also a Panel)